# Alternative for underscore delimiter

Tags: named-characters

If I want to have a variable name that contains multiple numbers but where it is important that the numbers be separated I would usually use underscores (as in C, e.g. p_3_23), dashes or dots (for filenames) but in Mathematica all these symbols are illegal.

What alternatives are there to format variable names containing multiple separate numbers? Somehow downvalues don't seem natural since not al numbers belong to a proper range or interval.

Comment: [Guidelines for readable variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31759/guidelines-on-giving-readable-names-to-variables)

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111337/41569?

Comment: Subscript[var, 1, 2, 3, 4]