# 3D stable fluids algorithm based on FFT

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, compile

This code is 3D extension of the code from my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274757/whats-wrong-with-this-fft-based-von-k%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n-vortex-street-simulation/274984#274984). As well known the stably fluids algorithm is some kind of predictor corrector algorithm - see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274757/whats-wrong-with-this-fft-based-von-k%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n-vortex-street-simulation/274984#274984). This algorithm includes 3 steps - advection, diffusion and projection. In Fourier space the diffusion and projection can be combine in one step as follows

$(u-u_n)/dt+(u.\nabla) u=0, (u_{n+1}-u)/dt+\nabla p-\mu \nabla^2 u=0$

Apply $\nabla .$ to the last equation and use $\nabla .u_n=0$, then we have

$\nabla^2 p-\nabla. u/dt-\mu \nabla^2( \nabla .u)=0$

Using FFT we can transform last 2 linear equations to the system of algebraic equations and express $u_{n+1}$ Fourier image as

$\vec{u}_{n+1}=(\vec{u}-(\vec{k}.\vec{u})\vec{k}/k^2)(1-\mu dtk^2)$

where $\vec{k}=(k_x,k_y,k_z),k^2=k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2$. The code in a case of 3D flow around cylinder can be written as follows

```
n = 64; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.0001; nt = 300; mat = 
 Table[E^(
  2 \[Pi] I (r - 1) (s - 1)/n), {r, 1, n}, {s, 1, 
   n}]; r = (Log[Flatten[mat]]/I) // DeleteDuplicates//N;
v = Table[{0., 0., 0.}, {n}, {n}, {n}];u0=.1;


Do[Do[If[i < 1 + n/16, v[[i, j, jz]] = {u0, 0., 0.}];
    If[(i - n/4)^2 + (j - n/2)^2 < (n/16)^2, 
     v[[i, j, jz]] = {0., 0., 0}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
   {ui, vi, wi} = 
    Table[ListInterpolation[v[[All, All, All, i]]], {i, 3}];
   v = Table[{i2, j2, jz2} = {i, j, jz} - n dt v[[i, j, jz]];
     {ui[i2, j2, jz2], vi[i2, j2, jz2], wi[i2, j2, jz2]} // Quiet, {i,
       n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
   {uf, vf, wf} = Table[Fourier[v[[All, All, All, i]]], {i, 3}]; 
   v = Table[{uf[[i, j, jz]], vf[[i, j, jz]], wf[[i, j, jz]]}, {i, 
      n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
   v = Table[x = r[[i]];
     y = r[[j]]; z = r[[jz]];
     k = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
     If[k > 
       0, (v[[i, j, 
          jz]] - (v[[i, j, jz]] . {x, y, z}) {x, y, z}/k) (1 - 
         mu dt k) , v[[i, j, jz]]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
   {ur, vr, wr} = 
    Table[InverseFourier[v[[All, All, All, i]]] // Re, {i, 3}]; 
   v = Table[{ur[[i, j, jz]], vr[[i, j, jz]], wr[[i, j, jz]]}, {i, 
      n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}]; vs[t] = v;, {t, 1, nt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Flow visualization in 2D at `z=n/2`

```
lst2D = Table[
   ImageRotate[
    Show[ListDensityPlot[vs[t][[All, All, n/2, 1]], 
      ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, 
      ImageSize -> Tiny], 
     Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{n/2, n/4}, n/16]}]], -Pi/2], {t, 15, 300, 
    5}];ListAnimate[lst2D]
```

[image: Figure 1]

3D flow visualization

```
lst3D = 
  Table[Show[
    ListDensityPlot3D[vs[t][[All, All, All, 1]], ColorFunction -> Hue,
      PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
     Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {-2., 1., 1.}, 
     OpacityFunction -> 0.05], 
    Graphics3D[{Blue, 
      Cylinder[{{0, n/2, n/4}, {n, n/2, n/4}}, n/16]}]], {t, 30, 300, 
    3}];ListAnimate[lst3D]
```

[image: Figure 2]

The code is working fine, but very slow. I try to compile code but without success. How can we improve computation time?

Update 1. As it proposed in the comment by yarchik we can use trilinear interpolation instead of `ListInterpolation`. The corresponding module `advect` was made for 3D flow simulation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261185/3d-stable-fluids-algorithm-to-simulate-transition-from-laminar-to-turbulent-flow). The code with this module is follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 64; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.0001; nt = 100; mat = 
 Table[E^(
  2 \[Pi] I (r - 1) (s - 1)/n), {r, 1, n}, {s, 1, 
   n}]; r = (Log[Flatten[mat]]/I) // DeleteDuplicates;
wr = vr = ur = Table[0, {n}, {n}, {n}]; u0 = .1;


advect[n_, d0_, u1_, v1_, w1_, dt_] := 
  Module[{x, y, z, d1, dt0, i, j, k, i0, i1, j0, j1, k0, k1, s0, s1, 
    t0, t1, p1, p0, d00, d10, d01, d11, cd0, cd1, xd, yd, zd, nx, ny, 
    nz}, nx = n; ny = n; nz = n; d1 = Table[0, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; 
   dt0 = dt n;
   Do[Do[
      Do[x = i - dt0 u1[[i, j, k]]; y = j - dt0 v1[[i, j, k]]; 
        z = k - dt0 w1[[i, j, k]];
        i0 = 
         Which[x <= 1, 1, 1 < x < nx - 1, Floor[x], True, nx - 1];
        i1 = i0 + 1;
        j0 = 
         Which[y <= 1, 1, 1 < y < ny - 1, Floor[y], True, ny - 1];
        j1 = j0 + 1; 
        k0 = Which[z <= 1, 1, 1 < z < nz - 1, Floor[z], True, 
          nz - 1];
        k1 = k0 + 1;(*Trilinear interpolation*)xd = x - i0; 
        yd = y - j0; zd = z - k0;
        d00 = d0[[i0, j0, k0]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j0, k0]] xd; 
        d01 = d0[[i0, j0, k1]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j0, k1]] xd; 
        d10 = d0[[i0, j1, k0]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j1, k0]] xd; 
        d11 = d0[[i0, j1, k1]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j1, k1]] xd;
        cd0 = d00 (1 - yd) + d10 yd; cd1 = d01 (1 - yd) + d11 yd; 
        d1[[i, j, k]] = cd0 (1 - zd) + cd1 zd;
        , {k, 2, nz - 1}];, {j, 2, ny - 1}];, {i, 1, nx}]; d1];
 Do[Do[If[
    i < 1 + n/16, {ur[[i, j, jz]], vr[[i, j, jz]], 
      wr[[i, j, jz]]} = {u0, 0, 0}];
   If[(i - n/4)^2 + (j - n/2)^2 < (n/16)^2, {ur[[i, j, jz]], 
      vr[[i, j, jz]], wr[[i, j, jz]]} = {0, 0, 0}], {i, n}, {j, 
    n}, {jz, n}];
  ui = advect[n, ur, ur, vr, wr, dt]; 
  vi = advect[n, vr, ur, vr, wr, dt]; 
  wi = advect[n, wr, ur, vr, wr, dt];
  uf = Fourier[ui]; vf = Fourier[vi]; wf = Fourier[wi]; 
  v = Table[{uf[[i, j, jz]], vf[[i, j, jz]], wf[[i, j, jz]]}, {i, 
     n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
  v = Table[x = r[[i]];
    y = r[[j]]; z = r[[jz]];
    k = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
    If[k > 
      0, (v[[i, j, 
         jz]] - (v[[i, j, jz]] . {x, y, z}) {x, y, z}/k) (1 - 
        mu dt k) , v[[i, j, jz]]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
  {ur, vr, wr} = 
   Table[InverseFourier[v[[All, All, All, i]]] // Re, {i, 3}]; 
  us[t] = ur; vs[t] = vr; ws[t] = wr;, {t, 1, nt}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization

```
Show[ListDensityPlot3D[
  Table[Norm[{ur[[i, j, jz]], vr[[i, j, jz]], wr[[i, j, jz]]}], {i, 
    n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}], AxesLabel -> {"z", "y", "x"}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, OpacityFunction -> 0.05, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2., 1., 1.}], 
 Graphics3D[{Blue, Cylinder[{{0, n/2, n/4}, {n, n/2, n/4}}, n/16]}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

This code also is very slow and can't be compiled due to mixture complex and real variables.

Update 2 Nevertheless we can compile part of code using idea from xzczd answer. In this code we add separate module `bcu` for boundary condition, and `onestep` to make advection step with boundary conditions

```
Clear["Global`*"]

mu = 1./10000; U0 = 0.; V0 = 0.; W0 = 0.; n = 64; nx = n; ny = 
 nz = n; {nx0, ny0, R0} = {n/4, n/2, n/16}; dt = .3; uinfl = .1;
n1 = n + 1; nt = 100;
u0 = Table[U0, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];
v0 = Table[V0, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; w0 = 
 Table[W0, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; mat = 
 Table[E^(
  2 \[Pi] I (r - 1) (s - 1)/n), {r, 1, n}, {s, 1, 
   n}]; r = (Log[Flatten[mat]]/I) // DeleteDuplicates // N;
Do[u0[[i, j, jz]] = If[i < 1 + n/16, uinfl, 0];, {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, 
   n}];

bcu[nx_, ny_, nz_, in_, up_, ud_, ul_, ur_, ub_] := 
  Module[{bd = ub}, 
   Do[bd[[nx, i, j]] = bd[[nx - 1, i, j]]; 
    bd[[1, i, j]] = bd[[2, i, j]];, {i, 2, ny - 1}, {j, 2, nz - 1}];
   Do[bd[[i, 1, j]] = ud;
    bd[[i, ny, j]] = up; bd[[i, j, 1]] = ul;
    bd[[i, j, nz]] = ur;, {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, ny}];
   bd];
advect[n_, nx_, ny_, nz_, d0_, u_, v_, w_, dt_] := 
  Module[{x, y, z, d1, dt0, i0, i1, j0, j1, k0, k1, s0, s1, t0, t1, 
    p1, p0, d00, d10, d01, d11, cd0, cd1, xd, yd, zd}, 
   d1 = ConstantArray[0, {nx, ny, nz}]; dt0 = dt n;
   Do[Do[
      Do[x = i - dt0 u[[i, j, k]]; y = j - dt0 v[[i, j, k]]; 
        z = k - dt0 w[[i, j, k]];
        i0 = 
         Which[x <= 1, 1, 1 < x < nx - 1, Floor[x], True, nx - 1];
        i1 = i0 + 1;
        j0 = 
         Which[y <= 1, 1, 1 < y < ny - 1, Floor[y], True, ny - 1];
        j1 = j0 + 1; 
        k0 = Which[z <= 1, 1, 1 < z < nz - 1, Floor[z], True, 
          nz - 1];
        k1 = k0 + 1;(*Trilinear interpolation*)xd = x - i0; 
        yd = y - j0; zd = z - k0;
        d00 = d0[[i0, j0, k0]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j0, k0]] xd; 
        d01 = d0[[i0, j0, k1]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j0, k1]] xd; 
        d10 = d0[[i0, j1, k0]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j1, k0]] xd; 
        d11 = d0[[i0, j1, k1]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j1, k1]] xd;
        cd0 = d00 (1 - yd) + d10 yd; cd1 = d01 (1 - yd) + d11 yd; 
        d1[[i, j, k]] = cd0 (1 - zd) + cd1 zd;
        , {k, 2, nz - 1}];, {j, 2, ny - 1}];, {i, 1, nx}]; d1];



onestep[n_, nx_, ny_, nz_, nx0_, ny0_, R0_, uin_, vin_, win_, dt_, 
   uinfl_] := Module[{u0, v0, w0},
   u0 = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];
   v0 = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; 
   w0 = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];
   u0 = uin; v0 = vin; w0 = win; 
   Do[u0[[i, j, jz]] = If[i < 1 + n/16, uinfl, u0[[i, j, jz]]];, {i, 
     n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}]; 
   Do[Do[u0[[i, j, k]] = 0;, {i, 
      nx0 - Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 
      nx0 + Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 1}], {j, ny0 - R0, 
     ny0 + R0, 1}, {k, 1, nz, 1}]; 
   u0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, u0]; 
   v0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, v0]; 
   w0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, w0];
   u0 = advect[n, nx, ny, nz, u0, u0, v0, w0, dt]; 
   v0 = advect[n, nx, ny, nz, v0, u0, v0, w0, dt]; 
   w0 = advect[n, nx, ny, nz, w0, u0, v0, w0, dt];
   Do[Do[u0[[i, j, k]] = 0; v0[[i, j, k]] = 0; 
     w0[[i, j, k]] = 0;, {i, nx0 - Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 
      nx0 + Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 1}], {j, ny0 - R0, 
     ny0 + R0, 1}, {k, 1, nz, 1}];
   u0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, u0]; 
   v0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, v0]; 
   w0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, w0];
   
   {u0, v0, w0}];

cf = With[{cg = Compile`GetElement, hp = HoldPattern, 
     dv = DownValues}, 
    Hold@Compile[{{u0argu, _Real, 3}, {v0argu, _Real, 
              3}, {w0argu, _Real, 
              3}, {n, _Integer}, {nx, _Integer}, {ny, _Integer}, {nz, \
_Integer}, {nx0, _Integer}, {ny0, _Integer}, {R0, _Integer}, {dt, \
_Real}, {uinfl, _Real}}, 
            Module[{u0 = u0argu, v0 = v0argu, w0 = w0argu, uu, vv, ww},
             {u0, v0, w0} = 
              onestep[n, nx, ny, nz, nx0, ny0, R0, u0, v0, w0, dt, 
               uinfl];
             {u0, v0, w0}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
            RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. dv@onestep /. 
         Flatten[dv /@ {advect, bcu}] /. 
        hp@ConstantArray[c_, {i_, j_, kc_}] :> 
         Table[0., {i}, {j}, {kc}] /. hp@Part[a__] :> cg[a] /. 
      hp[cg[a__] = rhs_] :> (Part[a] = rhs) // 
     ReleaseHold];
```

With this compilation code about 7 times faster

```
 Do[{ui, vi, wi} = 
   cf[u0, v0, w0, n, nx, ny, nz, nx0, ny0, R0, dt, uinfl];
  uf = Fourier[ui]; vf = Fourier[vi]; wf = Fourier[wi]; 
  v = Table[{uf[[i, j, jz]], vf[[i, j, jz]], wf[[i, j, jz]]}, {i, 
     n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
  v = Table[x = r[[i]];
    y = r[[j]]; z = r[[jz]];
    k = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
    If[k > 
      0, (v[[i, j, 
         jz]] - (v[[i, j, jz]] . {x, y, z}) {x, y, z}/k) (1 - 
        mu dt k) , v[[i, j, jz]]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
  {u0, v0, w0} = 
   Table[InverseFourier[v[[All, All, All, i]]] // Re, {i, 3}]; 
  us[t] = u0; vs[t] = v0; ws[t] = w0;, {t, 1, nt}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Update 3. We also can compile the complex part of the code as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

mu = 1./10000; U0 = 0.; V0 = 0.; W0 = 0.; n = 64; nx = n; ny = 
 nz = n; {nx0, ny0, R0} = {n/4, n/2, n/16}; dt = .3; uinfl = .1;
n1 = n + 1; nt = 300;
u0 = Table[U0, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];
v0 = Table[V0, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; w0 = 
 Table[W0, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; mat = 
 Table[E^(
  2 \[Pi] I (r - 1) (s - 1)/n), {r, 1, n}, {s, 1, 
   n}]; r = (Log[Flatten[mat]]/I) // DeleteDuplicates // N;
Do[u0[[i, j, jz]] = If[i < 1 + n/16, uinfl, 0];, {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, 
   n}];

bcu[nx_, ny_, nz_, in_, up_, ud_, ul_, ur_, ub_] := 
  Module[{bd = ub}, 
   Do[bd[[nx, i, j]] = bd[[nx - 1, i, j]]; 
    bd[[1, i, j]] = bd[[2, i, j]];, {i, 2, ny - 1}, {j, 2, nz - 1}];
   Do[bd[[i, 1, j]] = ud;
    bd[[i, ny, j]] = up; bd[[i, j, 1]] = ul;
    bd[[i, j, nz]] = ur;, {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, ny}];
   bd];
advect[n_, nx_, ny_, nz_, d0_, u_, v_, w_, dt_] := 
  Module[{x, y, z, d1, dt0, i0, i1, j0, j1, k0, k1, s0, s1, t0, t1, 
    p1, p0, d00, d10, d01, d11, cd0, cd1, xd, yd, zd}, 
   d1 = ConstantArray[0, {nx, ny, nz}]; dt0 = dt n;
   Do[Do[
      Do[x = i - dt0 u[[i, j, k]]; y = j - dt0 v[[i, j, k]]; 
        z = k - dt0 w[[i, j, k]];
        i0 = 
         Which[x <= 1, 1, 1 < x < nx - 1, Floor[x], True, nx - 1];
        i1 = i0 + 1;
        j0 = 
         Which[y <= 1, 1, 1 < y < ny - 1, Floor[y], True, ny - 1];
        j1 = j0 + 1; 
        k0 = Which[z <= 1, 1, 1 < z < nz - 1, Floor[z], True, 
          nz - 1];
        k1 = k0 + 1;(*Trilinear interpolation*)xd = x - i0; 
        yd = y - j0; zd = z - k0;
        d00 = d0[[i0, j0, k0]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j0, k0]] xd; 
        d01 = d0[[i0, j0, k1]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j0, k1]] xd; 
        d10 = d0[[i0, j1, k0]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j1, k0]] xd; 
        d11 = d0[[i0, j1, k1]] (1 - xd) + d0[[i1, j1, k1]] xd;
        cd0 = d00 (1 - yd) + d10 yd; cd1 = d01 (1 - yd) + d11 yd; 
        d1[[i, j, k]] = cd0 (1 - zd) + cd1 zd;
        , {k, 2, nz - 1}];, {j, 2, ny - 1}];, {i, 1, nx}]; d1];



onestep[n_, nx_, ny_, nz_, nx0_, ny0_, R0_, uin_, vin_, win_, dt_, 
   uinfl_] := Module[{u0, v0, w0},
   u0 = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];
   v0 = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; 
   w0 = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];
   u0 = uin; v0 = vin; w0 = win; 
   Do[u0[[i, j, jz]] = If[i < 1 + n/16, uinfl, u0[[i, j, jz]]];, {i, 
     n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}]; 
   Do[Do[u0[[i, j, k]] = 0;, {i, 
      nx0 - Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 
      nx0 + Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 1}], {j, ny0 - R0, 
     ny0 + R0, 1}, {k, 1, nz, 1}]; 
   u0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, u0]; 
   v0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, v0]; 
   w0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, w0];
   u0 = advect[n, nx, ny, nz, u0, u0, v0, w0, dt]; 
   v0 = advect[n, nx, ny, nz, v0, u0, v0, w0, dt]; 
   w0 = advect[n, nx, ny, nz, w0, u0, v0, w0, dt];
   Do[Do[u0[[i, j, k]] = 0; v0[[i, j, k]] = 0; 
     w0[[i, j, k]] = 0;, {i, nx0 - Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 
      nx0 + Round[Sqrt[R0^2 - (j - ny0)^2]], 1}], {j, ny0 - R0, 
     ny0 + R0, 1}, {k, 1, nz, 1}];
   u0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, u0]; 
   v0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, v0]; 
   w0 = bcu[nx, ny, nz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, w0];
   
   {u0, v0, w0}];

cf = With[{cg = Compile`GetElement, hp = HoldPattern, 
     dv = DownValues}, 
    Hold@Compile[{{u0argu, _Real, 3}, {v0argu, _Real, 
              3}, {w0argu, _Real, 
              3}, {n, _Integer}, {nx, _Integer}, {ny, _Integer}, {nz, \
_Integer}, {nx0, _Integer}, {ny0, _Integer}, {R0, _Integer}, {dt, \
_Real}, {uinfl, _Real}}, 
            Module[{u0 = u0argu, v0 = v0argu, w0 = w0argu, uu, vv, ww},
             {u0, v0, w0} = 
              onestep[n, nx, ny, nz, nx0, ny0, R0, u0, v0, w0, dt, 
               uinfl];
             {u0, v0, w0}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
            RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. dv@onestep /. 
         Flatten[dv /@ {advect, bcu}] /. 
        hp@ConstantArray[c_, {i_, j_, kc_}] :> 
         Table[0., {i}, {j}, {kc}] /. hp@Part[a__] :> cg[a] /. 
      hp[cg[a__] = rhs_] :> (Part[a] = rhs) // 
     ReleaseHold]; 
cf1 = With[{cg = Compile`GetElement, hp = HoldPattern}, 
   Hold@Compile[{{vargu, _Complex, 4}, {u0argu, _Complex, 
          3}, {v0argu, _Complex, 3}, {w0argu, _Complex, 
          3}, {n, _Integer}, {nx, _Integer}, {ny, _Integer}, {nz, \
_Integer}, {dt, _Real}, {mu, _Real}, {r, _Real, 1}}, 
        Module[{uf = u0argu, vf = v0argu, wf = w0argu, v = vargu, x, 
          y, z, k2}, 
         v = Table[{uf[[i, j, jz]], vf[[i, j, jz]], 
            wf[[i, j, jz]]}, {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}];
         v = Table[x = r[[i]];
           y = r[[j]]; z = r[[jz]];
           k2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
           
           If[k2 > 0, (v[[i, j, 
                jz]] - (v[[i, j, jz]] . {x, y, z}) {x, y, z}/k2) (1 - 
               mu dt k2) , v[[i, j, jz]]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {jz, n}]; 
         v], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
      hp@Part[a__] :> cg[a] /. hp[cg[a__] = rhs_] :> (Part[a] = rhs) //
     ReleaseHold];
```

With 2 compiled functions `cf,cf1` the code is in 86 times faster than without compilation. Also, due to `bcu` we can simulate 3D flow in a channel.

```
v = Table[{0., 0., 0.}, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}]; 
Do[{ui, vi, wi} = 
   cf[u0, v0, w0, n, nx, ny, nz, nx0, ny0, R0, dt, uinfl];
  uf = Fourier[ui]; vf = Fourier[vi]; wf = Fourier[wi]; 
  v1 = cf1[v, uf, vf, wf, n, nx, ny, nz, dt, mu, r];
  {u0, v0, w0} = 
   Table[InverseFourier[v1[[All, All, All, i]]] // Re, {i, 3}]; 
  us[t] = u0; vs[t] = v0; 
  ws[t] = w0;, {t, 1, nt}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization

```
lst3D = Table[
  Show[ListDensityPlot3D[us[t], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
    PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
    Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {-2., 1., 1.}, 
    OpacityFunction -> 0.05], 
   Graphics3D[{Blue, 
     Cylinder[{{0, n/2, n/4}, {n, n/2, n/4}}, n/16]}]], {t, 20, nt, 
   4}]; ListAnimate[lst3D]
```

[image: Figure4]

Comment: Maybe linear interpolation is sufficient ?

Comment: @yarchik Do you mean trilinear interpolation as in Update 2 on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261185/3d-stable-fluids-algorithm-to-simulate-transition-from-laminar-to-turbulent-flow ?

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea. I thought it might be too expensive and not compilable to construct interpolation function each time-step.

Comment: @yarchik Yes, you are right. With trilinear interpolation the compiled code in 100 times faster than with `ListInterpolation` without compilation.

Comment: Impressive speed up!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a 3D version of [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275117/1871):

```
SetAttributes[compile, HoldAll];
compile[argu__] := 
 With[{cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
    Hold@Compile[argu, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. 
      Part -> cg /. HoldPattern[cg[a__] = rhs_] :> (Part[a] = rhs)] // ReleaseHold //
   Last

interrule = inter[valueL_, valueR_, scale_] :> (1 - scale) valueL + scale valueR;

force…and…advection = 
  Hold@compile[{{arg, _Real, 4}, {dt, _Real}}, 
       Module[{u, v, w, unew, vnew, wnew, nx, ny, nz, inew, jnew, knew, iL, jL, kL, 
         iR, jR, kR},
        {u, v, w} = arg; {nx, ny, nz} = Dimensions@v;
        unew = vnew = wnew = Table[0., {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];
        Do[If[i < 1 + nx/16.,
          u[[i, j, k]] = 0.1; v[[i, j, k]] = 0.; w[[i, j, k]] = 0.];
         If[(i - nx/4.)^2 + (j - ny/2.)^2 < (nx/16.)^2,
          u[[i, j, k]] = 0.; v[[i, j, k]] = 0.; w[[i, j, k]] = 0.], {i, nx}, {j, 
          ny}, {k, nz}];
        Do[inew = Mod[i - nx dt u[[i, j, k]], nx - 1, 1];
         jnew = Mod[j - nx dt v[[i, j, k]], ny - 1, 1];
         knew = Mod[k - nx dt w[[i, j, k]], nz - 1, 1];
         iL = Floor@inew; jL = Floor@jnew; kL = Floor@knew;
         iR = iL + 1; jR = jL + 1; kR = kL + 1;
         unew[[i, j, k]] = interfunc[u];
         vnew[[i, j, k]] = interfunc[v];
         wnew[[i, j, k]] = interfunc[w], {i, nx}, {j, ny}, {k, nz}];
        {unew, vnew, wnew}
        ]] /. interfunc[v_] :> inter[
       inter[
        inter[v[[iL, jL, kL]], v[[iL, jR, kL]], jnew - jL],
        inter[v[[iR, jL, kL]], v[[iR, jR, kL]], jnew - jL], inew - iL],
       inter[
        inter[v[[iL, jL, kR]], v[[iL, jR, kR]], jnew - jL],
        inter[v[[iR, jL, kR]], v[[iR, jR, kR]], jnew - jL], inew - iL], 
       knew - kL] //. interrule // ReleaseHold;

viscosity…and…conservation = 
  compile[{{arg, _Complex, 4}, dt, mu}, 
   Module[{u, v, w, x, y, z, nx, ny, nz, k, k2},
    {u, v, w} = arg; {nx, ny, nz} = Dimensions@v;
    Do[
     x = Mod[i - 1, nx, -nx/2.];
     y = Mod[j - 1, ny, -ny/2.];
     z = Mod[k - 1, nz, -nz/2.];
     k2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
     With[{coef = (1 - k2 mu dt (Pi/(nx/2.))^2), 
       mid = x u[[i, j, k]] + y v[[i, j, k]] + z w[[i, j, k]]},
       If[k2 > 0,
       u[[i, j, k]] = coef (u[[i, j, k]] - x mid/k2);
       v[[i, j, k]] = coef (v[[i, j, k]] - y mid/k2);
       w[[i, j, k]] = coef (w[[i, j, k]] - z mid/k2), 0.]], {i, nx}, {j, ny}, {k, 
      nz}];
    {u, v, w}]];

nx = 64; ny = nx; nz = nx; dt = 0.3; mu = 0.001; nt = 300;
v = Table[0., {3}, {nx}, {ny}, {nz}];

vlst = Table[v = force…and…advection[v, dt];
    v = Fourier /@ v;
    v = viscosity…and…conservation[v, dt, mu];
    v = InverseFourier /@ v // Re, {t, nt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {40.3973, Null} *)

arrayplot = ArrayPlot[#, DataReversed -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &;

vlst[[-1]] // First // #[[All, All, nz/2]]\[Transpose] & // arrayplot
```

[image]

```
vlst[[-1]] // First // 
  ListDensityPlot3D[#, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PlotRange -> All] & // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

For 2GHz dual core laptop, the timing for 300×64×64×64 grid is about 40 seconds. Limited by the RAM of my laptop, it's a bit troublesome for me to make better visualization (the GIF in question isn't obtained with 300 time steps, I guess?), so I'd like to stop here.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but a question: What is the black magic with the three dots in the "force…and…advection" variable? How's this possible???

Comment: This answer is very useful (+1).

Comment: @Hans It's actually `\[Ellipsis]` :D . In Chinese this symbol is used for ellipsis, so it's relatively easy for me to input this symbol using Chinese [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method).

Comment: Oh I see! I always envied other programming languages, e.g. Python etc, where you can use underscores etc in the variables, but now I'm doing this :D

Comment: @Hans Some other alternatives of underscore are mentioned here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111337/1871 :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had a look in the post and I think ``\[Ellipsis]`` and ``\[LetterSpace]`` are the best, as I'm not a big fan of ``camelCase`` :-)

Comment: @xzczd It looks like your interpolation in advection module is periodic?

Comment: @Alex Yes. Oh, I didn't notice your interpolation isn't periodic. If the velocity near the boundary is not too large, non-periodic interpolation may be OK, but generally I think this isn't a very good idea, because the extrapolation of `Interpolation` can be wild. Also, naive extrapolation isn't a good choice for approximation of transparent bounday AFAIK.

Comment: @xzczd Usually we use separate module for boundary conditions like on this page https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261185/3d-stable-fluids-algorithm-to-simulate-transition-from-laminar-to-turbulent-flow .

Comment: @xzczd Please, note that in my code  `mu = 0.0001` while in your code  `mu = 0.001`.

Comment: @Alex This isn't a big issue. As mentioned in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274757/whats-wrong-with-this-fft-based-von-k%c3%a1rm%c3%a1n-vortex-street-simulation/275117#comment687197_274984), the coefficient `(1 - k mu dt (Pi/(n/2))^2)` actually plays the role of a quite mild filter. Using `mu=0.001` or `0.0001` or even `0`, the outputs are visually the same.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks again, finally I got compiled code with time about 70 s for 300 steps - see Update3 in my post.

Comment: @Alex On my laptop the timing is about 120 s. This is a bit surprising. The reason might be the Dirichlet b.c. is cheaper.

Comment: @xzczd Actually periodic bc are cheapest. May be FFT faster without compilation?

Comment: @Alex I haven't compile FFT, either… Actually `Fourier` and `InverseFourier` are not compilable: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/1871

Comment: @xzczd Yes, you are right. Then there is only difference in  `Transpose` usage?

Comment: @Alex I think you're right, after re-designing the code to make it now only works with $3×n_x×n_y×n_z$ tensor, it only takes 40 seconds for `nt=300` on my laptop. Havve a look :) .

Comment: @xzczd It is fantastic result! Thank you very match!